# Java lambda meta factory

Tags: java, lambda-metafactory

```
CallSite lambdaFactory = LambdaMetafactory.metafactory(
   lookup, 
   "call",
   MethodType.methodType(BiConsumer.class), 
   MethodType.methodType(void.class,Long.class), 
      lookup.findVirtual(CallClass.class, "call",       
   MethodType.methodType(void.class,Long.class)),
   MethodType.methodType(void.class));
lambdaFactory.getTarget().invoke(callId);


private void call(Long callId){
     ---
}
```

I am getting this exception
java.lang.invoke.LambdaConversionException: Incorrect number of parameters for instance method invokeVirtual call:()void; 0 captured parameters, 0 functional interface method parameters, 0 implementation parameters

Answer (score 5):

There is almost everything wrong in this invocation:

1. `CallSite lambdaFactory = LambdaMetafactory.metafactory(`
2. `lookup,`
3. `"call",` this must be the name of the interface method needed to be implemented. For `BiConsumer`, this is `"accept"`.
4. `MethodType.methodType(BiConsumer.class),` this is the *invokedType* which must match the `invoke` call at (10).
5. `MethodType.methodType(void.class,Long.class),` this is the signature of the interface method to implement at the bytecode level, i.e. after type erasure. For `BiConsumer`, this is always `MethodType.methodType(void.class, Object.class, Object.class)`.
6. `lookup.findVirtual(CallClass.class, "call",`
7. `MethodType.methodType(void.class,Long.class)),`
8. `MethodType.methodType(void.class)` this is the specialization of the interface or identical to (5) when the interface is not generic. In either case, the number of parameters must match with (5). For your case, you likely want match the target method, so it must be `MethodType.methodType(void.class, CallClass.class, Long.class)`.
9. `);`
10. `lambdaFactory.getTarget().invoke(callId);` the `invoke` call must match the *invokedType* signature specified in (4). The specified arguments are the values to be *captured*. Since you’ve chosen to implement `BiConsumer`, which has the same functional signature as your target method, there is no use for an additional value.

The biggest problem is the mismatch between (4) and (10), as it makes it unclear what you actually want to achieve. Do you want to capture an existing `callId` as `invoke(callId)` suggests or do you want to create a non-capturing function, as the *invokedType* argument and the choice of `BiConsumer` suggest?

For a straight-forward `BiConsumer` generation, the fixed code would look like:

```
CallSite callSite = LambdaMetafactory.metafactory(
   lookup, "accept", MethodType.methodType(BiConsumer.class), 
   MethodType.methodType(void.class, Object.class, Object.class),
   lookup.findVirtual(CallClass.class,"call", MethodType.methodType(void.class,Long.class)),
   MethodType.methodType(void.class, CallClass.class, Long.class)
);
BiConsumer<CallClass,Long> bc = (BiConsumer<CallClass, Long>)callSite.getTarget().invoke();
```

If you want to capture an existing `callId`, you would have to change the functional interface to a type not expecting a second argument. Further, you’d need an adapter, because the `LambdaMetafactory` expects captured arguments first and the interface method arguments afterwards. So, since this is not supported directly, the simplest solution is to generate a `BiConsumer<CallClass,Long>` as above, followed by `Consumer<CallClass> c = cc -> bc.apply(cc, callId);`, capturing the existing `callId`.

Only if you also have an already existing `CallClass` instance you want to bind, you can do it directly:

```
CallSite callSite = LambdaMetafactory.metafactory(
   lookup, "run", MethodType.methodType(Runnable.class, LambdaMF.class, Long.class), 
   MethodType.methodType(void.class),
   lookup.findVirtual(LambdaMF.class, "call", MethodType.methodType(void.class,Long.class)),
   MethodType.methodType(void.class)
);
Runnable r = (Runnable)callSite.getTarget().invoke(callClassInstance, callId);
```